# Resilience of postgres restarting during logical replication

Tags: postgresql

I'm migrating my data from one postgres instance to another. My database is ~25TB. I'm using Postgres' builtin [logical replication mechanism using publications and subscriptions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/logical-replication.html).

I found `pg_subscription_rel` which [tracks the state of each replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/catalog-pg-subscription-rel.html). For each `srsubstate` (`i`, `d`, `s`, `r`), what happens if either the subscriber or publisher restarts?

EDIT: my guess is that when a subscription enters the `s` or `r` state, a restart of either the publisher or subscriber will not result in the subscription being recopied. I'd also guess that if a restart happens during the `i` or `d` phases, the table would need to be recopied.